# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_object'

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I'm using [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) to get pages from a pdf file, which is working fine for most of the files.
But for a specific file, I'm getting the exception below:

```
  File "/home/obr01/python-venv/opencapture/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf/_page.py", line 2342, in __getitem__
    len_self = len(self)
  File "/home/obr01/python-venv/opencapture/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf/_page.py", line 2333, in __len__
    return self.length_function()
  File "/home/obr01/python-venv/opencapture/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf/_reader.py", line 452, in _get_num_pages
    self._flatten()
  File "/home/obr01/python-venv/opencapture/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf/_reader.py", line 1185, in _flatten
    pages = catalog["/Pages"].get_object()  # type: ignore
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_object'
```

Apparently this is comming from the value of "/Pages" in the Reader trailer, which is "None" for this file :

```py
pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(file_path, strict=False)
print(pdf_reader.trailer['/Root']['/Pages'])
```

Output :

```
Object 2178 0 not defined.
None
```

Is there any way to handle this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem, I manage to solve it using [pikepdf](https://pypi.org/project/pikepdf/).

Code :

```py
    with pikepdf.Pdf.open(pdf_path, allow_overwriting_input=True) as _pdf:
        _pdf.save(pdf_path)
```

Opening the PDF file and saving it again fixes the PDF trailer.

Also, here is the issue created in pypdf github project : https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/1689